# Is there going to be a book all about Hoid?

Tags: cosmere

Is Brandon Sanderson planning to write a book following Hoid's story? I heard somewhere that he was, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "future production" types of questions are not on topic here.

Comment: https://brandonsanderson.com/a-quick-update-on-my-writing-projects/

Comment: @Möoz In most cases, I might agree, but Brandon Sanderson has laid out a pretty specific timeline of his future books. Therefore, you can objectively say one way or the other if he's planning on writing such a book, which he is.

Comment: paging u/mistborn...oh, does that not work here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, kinda.

*Dragonsteel* won't be about Hoid exclusively, but it will be set on his homeworld and it will feature him as a major character/narrator.

> **Dragonsteel**
>   This story (the story of the shattering of Adonalsium, as told by Hoid) is next-to-last in my sequence of cosmere novels (though it’s first chronologically). So don’t expect it until Stormlight 10 is done.
>
> Status: A long way off. Though it might still beat that one book by that other author.
>   <sub>[State of the Sanderson - 2016](https://brandonsanderson.com/state-of-the-sanderson-2016/)</sub>

And then he is supposed to be a main character towards the end of *Mistborn*.

> **Questioner**
>   When are we going to get Hoid’s book?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson**
>   Hoid has 6 books, they are the 3 books of Dragonsteel, which are prequels and the last Mistborn trilogy of the nine book arc will have him as a main character. I won't say they're "his" books, but he is one of the primary protagonists.
>   <sub>[Words of Radiance Signing - Arcanum](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/224-words-of-radiance-san-francisco-signing/#e7155)</sub>

Comment: Worth noting that his comment about the Mistborn Arc has changed slightly since he made that comment.  Mistborn is now planned as a 13 book Arc instead of nine, because Alloy of Law spawned a second Era that was not part of his original arc.

Comment: "Though it might still beat that one book by that other author." Is presumably a stab at Rothfuss. Oof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Brandon is planning on writing a book series called Dragonsteel which is Hoid's origin story as well as the story of

> the Shattering of Adonalsium

Brandon's [2016 State of the Sanderson](https://brandonsanderson.com/state-of-the-sanderson-2016/) says this will be "as told by Hoid" which I take to mean he's either the POV character or narrator. The [2017 State of the Sanderson](https://brandonsanderson.com/state-of-the-sanderson-2017/#potential) simply says it's Hoid's origin story.

Either way, he's been pretty consistent that it won't be written until The Stormlight Archive is done, so we're probably looking at a few decades before we see it.